# phpunit assert that the element has a value

Tags: yii, phpunit, assert, functional-testing, assertions

I'm using phpunit for the Yii framework. Tried creating a functional test. How to test that the existing element or label has a value.
I have read that

```
$this->assertQuery('input#valid_from[value=""]',1);
```

is used to check for empty values. But in my case I want to check that a label or readonly field has value.

Comment: The HTML of said label or readonly field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer from http://phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html,
I have to use `assertElementValueEquals(string $locator, string $text)` or `assertElementValueNotEquals(string $locator, string $text)`.